# How do I update a state in redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

**reducers.js**

**this is my initialState**

```
const initialState = {
  transfusions: [],
};
```

**Here is my Switch logic**

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TRANSFUSIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        transfusions: action.payload,
      };
    case ADD_TRANSFUSION:
      return {
        ...state,
        transfusions: [...state.transfusions, action.payload],
      };
    case UPDATE_TRANSFUSION:
      console.log(action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        transfusions: state.transfusions.map(
          (transfusion) => transfusion.id === action.payload.id ? {
            ...state,
            transfusion: action.payload
          } : transfusions
        ),
      };
    case DELETE_TRANSFUSION:
      return {
        ...state,
        transfusions: state.transfusions.filter(
          (transfusion) => transfusion.id !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I updated in the backend successfully but how do I update the frontend. I tried this method it works but it always needs to refresh the page to show me the updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue. I used this code:

```
 case UPDATE_TRANSFUSION:
      const transfusionsExisted = state.transfusions.filter(
        (transfusion) => transfusion.id !== action.payload.id
      );
      return {
        transfusions: [action.payload, ...transfusionsExisted],
      };
```

I deleted the record I wanted to update first and then pushed the new record.

I hope it will help you if you are suffering as I suffered from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`transfusions: state.transfusions.map(` is relying on the old state so it is always one step behind

You can modify your code to something like this:

```
   const transfusionExists = state.transfusions.find(t => t.id === action.payload.id)
   if(!transfusionExists) state.transfusions.push(action.payload)
   return {
        ...state
        ),
      };
```

Comment: Can you include how and where you dispatch that action?